# How to set a variable for the parent's css class using the parent's variable for its id?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So what I want to do first is to set a variable for the parent using the id of it. Then I want to use this variable to find the css class of the parent and set a new variable again. It's important use the variable for the parent's id because later I want to change HTML style of this class with the specific id. My JS works fine without "var parent = parentid.find('.parent');"... I don't know what's wrong.

```js
var parentid = document.getElementById('1');
var parent = parentid.find('.parent');
parent.style.background = "yellow";
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 2.5ex;
  max-height: 12.5ex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="1">
  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using `jQuery`?

Comment: The script is inserted... but I think I didn't use it yet. I tried to insert a child div into the parent div and changed the JS. Still doesn't work...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I tried to outline the aspects which might be confusing for you at this point in my answer. For your specific case, since you're already loading `jQuery` in your project and it has a friendlier syntax, I recommend you stick to it and use their extensive documentation to achieve your goals, trying not to mix it with vanilla syntax. When you decide to move on to vanilla, you should try to achieve tasks without using jQuery at all.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) doesn't include the selector itself into it's search, you have to use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) (begins with the current element) instead:

```js
var parentid = $('#1');
var parent = parentid.closest('.parent');
$(parent).css('background-color', 'gold');
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent" id="1">
  The CSS 'background-color' property is PINK.
</div>
```

Comment: that's jQuery :) find() was javascript, but miused by the op ....https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: I asked if it's jQuery under the question, still no response. Indeed, it wouldn't work in `jQuery` either. But `closest()` here is kind of useless. You already got the right element. But here are my 2¢: the question needs to be a lot more specific to deserve the amount of attention it received :).

Comment: Thanks, I noted that it's jQuery, maybe someone will find it useful. Well if I get OP right, he is about to change variable later, but I also find the second line of his JS useless, or maybe I didn't clearly get the idea.

Comment: I am sorry I can't be more specific. I wanted to cut the code so only the main problem is visible. Why I am using so useless lines of course won't be visible for you because I use it in a much larger code which has multiple functions and I know that I shouldn't post unnecessary stuff here. The keyword is: tumblr theme. So yeah I am still a noob in JS and I forgot that .find() is from JQuery but to a noob it doesn't seem so. I am thankful to you helping me realize that I did such a noob mistake.

Comment: @DidiKong Oh it's okay, no need to be that categorical to yourself! :).. Well, take a look at Michael's answer, I have a feeling it might be a solution that you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, as long as the element only has a single class, you can just reference `className`

```js
var parentid = document.getElementById('1');
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName(parentid.className)[0];
parent.style.background = "yellow";
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 2.5ex;
  max-height: 12.5ex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="1">
  Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
</div>
```